# R - Fuzzy find and recode

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning, recode, fuzzy-comparison

I am cleaning demographic data that has been submitted by 10+ school districts and the submissions are not standardized/uniform.  I would like to find patterns and recode them so that the data is clean and simple.

Let's say I have a variable called `Race`, and one of the categories is `Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander`.

School A submits this category as `Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander`.  School B submits this category as `Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander`.  School C submits this category as `Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander`.

How could I recode this such that if R sees the word `Pacific` anywhere in the variable, it will recode to `Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander`?

Here is the original data:

```
df_original <- data.frame(Race=c("Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
                                 "Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander",
                                 "Black or African American", "Black", "Black/African American"))
```

Here is the ideal cleaned data:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(Race=c("Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander","Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander",
                                "Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander","Black - African American",
                                "Black - African American","Black - African American"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grepl()` will return `TRUE` for strings that contain "Pacific" and `False` otherwise. Use that to subset your vector and replace with the string you want:

```
df_original$Race[grepl("Pacific", df_original$Race)] <- "Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander"
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is particularly simple and useful because of the `ignore.case=TRUE` argument that can be added to `grepl`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_detect` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_original %>% 
    mutate(Race2 = case_when(str_detect(Race, '\\bPacific\\b') ~
      "Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander", 
            TRUE ~ "Black - African American"))
```

-output

```
                                Race                              Race2
1 Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
2          Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
3       Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
4                 Black or African American           Black - African American
5                                     Black           Black - African American
6                    Black/African American           Black - African American
```

---

Another option is to create a key/value dataset with the pattern and its corresponding value to replace and then do a `regex_left_join` (from `fuzzyjoin`) with the original data

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
keydat <- tibble(Race = c("Pacific", "Black"), 
   Race2 = c("Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander", "Black - African American"))
regex_left_join(df_original, keydat) %>%
        transmute(Race = Race2)
#Joining by: "Race"
#                                Race
#1 Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
#2 Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
#3 Native Hawaiian - Pacific Islander
#4           Black - African American
#5           Black - African American
#6           Black - African American
```